# Display the post date in title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am very new in WP, I want to change the title display on the portal to show also the post date in brackets using a filter ? how can I do it ?
when I try this (solution of @Dre) ; I get also date with the top menu:

```
function my_add_date_to_title($title, $id) {
    $date_format = get_option('date_format');
    $date = get_the_date($date_format, $id); // Should return a string
    return $title . ' (' . $date . ')';
}
add_filter('the_title','my_add_date_to_title',10,2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off editing your page templates to simply output the date; it's quicker and makes it much more obvious and easier to find later on. Apply content via filters can make it harder to tracker down *where* content is coming from.

Having said that, if you're determined to do it via filters, here's what you'd need to add to your `functions.php` file:

```
/* Adds date to end of title 
 * @uses Hooked to 'the_title' filter
 * @args $title(string) - Incoming title
 * @args $id(int) - The post ID
 */
function my_add_date_to_title($title, $id) {

    // Check if we're in the loop or not
    // This should exclude menu items
    if ( !is_admin() && in_the_loop() ) {

        // First get the default date format
        // Alternatively, you can specify your 
        // own date format instead
        $date_format = get_option('date_format');

        // Now get the date
        $date = get_the_date($date_format, $id); // Should return a string

        // Now put our string together and return it
        // You can of course tweak the markup here if you want
        $title .= ' (' . $date . ')';
     }

    // Now return the string
    return $title;
}

// Hook our function to the 'the_title' filter
// Note the last arg: we specify '2' because we want the filter
// to pass us both the title AND the ID to our function
add_filter('the_title','my_add_date_to_title',10,2);
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: your solution works, but I see also the date with the top menu elements !!!

Comment: @user2997418 Ah, yes, I forgot about those. I've updated it to account for it.