# Add current time on a specific post title in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display current time on a specific post title in WordPress. How Can I do?

I found some solution and here's the close one:

[Display the post date in title in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026088/display-the-post-date-in-title-in-wordpress)

--

It will add current time on every post title, so I adding a condition by using is_single:

```
if ( is_single(1137) ) {
add_filter('the_title','my_add_date_to_title',10,2);
}
```

But it's not working.

How can I do?

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: Provide code snippet of function `my_add_date_to_title` which You call on filter.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move your condition into the function so:

```
function my_add_date_to_title($title, $id) {

  if ( $id != 1137 ) {

  //your function in here

  }

}
add_filter('the_title','my_add_date_to_title',10,2);
```